# How to correctly type an object with alternate keys in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I want to create a TypeScript type that involves a set of fixed keys, plus a set of alternate groups of keys, such as:

```
type Props = {
   id: string
} & (
{
  height: number, 
  width: number
} 
  | {color: string}
)
```

Now, in this case, it correctly enforces that each of the groups have all the properties of that group, or none of them, i.e.: I can't use `height` without also using `width`.

Now, if I want to also allow an alternative without any of the optional keys, the only option that I know actually gives the desired result is by using `{}` as an alternative.

But lint rule `@typescript-eslint/ban-types` disallows that, saying that depending on the  use case I should either `Record<string, unknown>`, `unknown` or `Record<string, never>`.

But none of these really work for this case. If I use `unknown` or `Record<string, never>` or `object` TS doesn't allow any of the keys in the alternatives. If I use `Record<string, unknown>` it doesn't allow any key unless I fill one of the alternative key groups.

Is there another way of doing this that I'm missing, or should I ignore the lint rule to achieve this?

Comment: Note that due to the relaxed excess-property check on unions, the `Props` above will also allow `{ id: 'i', width: 0, color: 'c' }`, and if you add the `{}`, it will even allow `{ id: 'i', height: 0 }`: https://tsplay.dev/mLyQKW

Comment: Huh, that's weird. I don't have the code before me, but I'm positive that I'm able to reach the desired result with this syntax in our app. Could it be a TS version issue?

Comment: @Oblosys I just read a bit about excess type checking, and seems like there is a range of different rules for when it's allowed or not. Curiously, looks like the case you reproduced is not supposed to work, so I don't know the explanation. But for React Component props it does check.

Comment: There's not a lot of documentation about it, but it's been like this since v3.5, and before that you could even have an excess property with an incorrect type. Here you can see it applied to components: https://tsplay.dev/WJ5zvm It is by design though: [release notes 3.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#improved-excess-property-checks-in-union-types)

Answer (score 2):

I find in React that overloads a better case for this.

You can create an overload for each pattern that you want to support.

```
import React from 'react'

type RequiredProps = { id: string }

type SizeProps = { height: number, width: number } 
type ColorProps = { color: string }
type AllOptionProps = SizeProps | ColorProps


function MyComponent(props: RequiredProps): JSX.Element
function MyComponent(props: RequiredProps & SizeProps): JSX.Element
function MyComponent(props: RequiredProps & ColorProps): JSX.Element

function MyComponent(props: RequiredProps & Partial<AllOptionProps>) {
    console.log(props.id)
    if ('width' in props) console.log(props.width)
    if ('color' in props) console.log(props.color)
    return <></>
}

const a = <MyComponent id='abc' />
const b = <MyComponent id='abc' width={50} height={100} />
const c = <MyComponent id='abc' color='red' />

const d = <MyComponent id='abc' width={50} /> // error
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20220921#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCmATzCUSQEcBXYIgEwAUcwBnOALxwA3nGDsAXHF4wowAHYBzOAF8KVWvQDKwAF5JuEPoJFwAFkmCKzMKfOYgARkigAaOAHdxMM3YfOoVTgNOjgAYQgAG2hDYyFRNCjoKRk5JVUQ+gBBSMiAeTAYYAh5WP4hHX0yuAAfcKSoMvVKckxmeQxi+TgAWWoI8BKkeRgACjAeXilkFjYkLkmASikAKS0ADQA6AFFIpBBhmAo2jqKS3v7cSHlD8cnpplYOaoAyOEqDJdWNnb2DkeO7U65z6A2utwmRimDFmz0mcDeEWijS+cDWW12+0OzROwO6oKuQxGdyhD1h81ecE4KFgwBQkQAPDl8oUumUAHyLEQUOC8uCJeS8KJITbRRQkvibcSLHl84CYOCjfBedg+fBibqQvhcgVCvaiiDirW8TYqnwy8h8sQKpWJZHqhRwY06kp6kViiUmu3QC1WogwZhQboM9kMgD07IoahauvgKBMDIJgxuIzE7AEwnwKEcaHwKjgEYosbgjgTSfBqfEGazObznm8ZgzAFYAAz5ixWGwZgCMLbbBcj5GLaDLl2ThzT1ezufz3qgAkI83VhZjrvg7FHYKJ8CrmendbNjeErfzEYLYbgLhwUCAA)

---

A second approach is to create a union where all props are in all members, but are forced to `undefined` if you say you can have them.

```
import React from 'react'

type RequiredProps = { id: string }

type NoOptionsProps = {
    height?: undefined,
    width?: undefined,
    color?: undefined
}
type SizeProps = {
    height: number,
    width: number,
    color?: undefined
} 
type ColorProps = {
    height?: undefined,
    width?: undefined,
    color: string
}
type Props = RequiredProps & (NoOptionsProps | SizeProps | ColorProps)

function MyComponent(props: Props) {
    console.log(props.id)
    console.log(props.width)
    console.log(props.color)
    return <></>
}

const a = <MyComponent id='abc' />
const b = <MyComponent id='abc' width={50} height={100} />
const c = <MyComponent id='abc' color='red' />

const d = <MyComponent id='abc' width={50} /> // error
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20220921#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCmATzCUSQEcBXYIgEwAUcwBnOALxwA3nGDsAXHF4wowAHYBzOAF8KVWvQByEAPJgYwCPN7cIfQSIpwbcABZJgiuzAD8U5vPZJMCpOwAaa1sAd3EYO3c4T29feX8g8ls4NAgAG2gomJ8-dgo1cho6OABlYAAvJDMLIWFgmwcnFyl5ZhAAIyQoROSw9giWts7u+pT0zI8vHPi88hU4DWKAYXGoav5a0cbnN0nY3J7Q8Mi96YTR1IyoKRk5JXzF+nXLZBY2f2eAMjgACh19QzGUw8fgAH1KFSqILg4JWV3WAEp1ORMJ4MEZ5HAALLUFbgYxIeQwH5gEFSRFWJK2VImdJIAB0GUUJJB9PESKpNhpvDpjIgzNJ5l49L6EQ5yW5vKZLKF9Mu0HFtiIMGYUExAB4AHzqgD0moelHI3PgKEs6pxeMg8SJYnYAmE+BQ7TQ+Hmeooxrg7TNFtwVsJ8HE9sdztdcFFdntAFYAAzzbYue0ARhjcbg7qNQPgaB9uL9BJtQYdTpd83lUAEhH8+HT+sNnvYuctBcDduLofmEejab16Z1cC6OCgQA)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Alex. Though I personally find these options a bit too verbose. I just wanted to know if there's some more direct alternative, since the lint message seems to imply that there's no case that can't be handled by the other alternatives...

Comment: Yeah, it may imply that, but in my experience, it's not true. What you dont want is this, albeit contrived, situation https://tsplay.dev/w23dbN. But if that scenario is fine with you, then you can always just tell eslint to stuff it, or use `Record<never, never>` which is the same as `{}` but eslint doesn't complain and at least doesn't look like a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can try intersection of `FC`:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

interface Base {
  id: string
}

interface WithRect extends Base {
  height: number,
  width: number
}

interface WithColor extends Base {
  color: string
}


type Result = FC<WithColor> & FC<WithRect> & FC<Base>

const App: Result = (props) => <p></p>

const jsx = <App id="hello" color="green" /> // ok
const jsx____ = <App id="hello" /> // ok
const jsx___ = <App id="hello" width={1} height={1} /> // ok


const jsx_ = <App id="hello" color="green" height={1} /> // expected error
const jsx__ = <App id="hello" height={1} /> // expected error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpLqgm)

This behavior is similar to function overloading, I would even say 95% similar but not equal.

If you are interested in typing React component props, see my articles [my blog](https://catchts.com/react-props) and [dev.to](https://dev.to/captainyossarian/how-to-type-react-props-as-a-pro-2df2)